# Dynamic Menu Contribution on View ToolBar thru plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse, plugins, e4, pde

We are trying to fill the Toolbar of the View using MenuService as documented in this tutorial
http://appddeevvmeanderings.blogspot.in/2007/10/eclipse-defining-your-own-toolbar-menu.html

In the above tutorial, he creates a Toolbar in a View and reads the Commands from the plugin.xml

```
toolbar = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);
       getMenuService().populateContributionManager(toolbar, "toolbar:yourapp.toolbarX");
       toolbar.createControl(p);
```

In our code instead of creating a ToolBarManager we take the ToolBarManager of the View.

```
toolbar = getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();
           getMenuService().populateContributionManager((ToolBarManager)toolbar, "toolbar:YourID?after=additions");
//         ((ToolBarManager)toolbar).createControl(parent);
           toolbar.update(true);
           getViewSite().getActionBars().updateActionBars();
```

This doesn't work. Any help would be highly appreciated. I would want to add this to the Toolbar of the View and not to my own custom ToolBar. It seems to be working in Eclipse 3.8 and not in Eclipse 4x onwards.

Comment: Why aren't you just using the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to contribute to the view toolbar?

Comment: We are in the process of migrating some old eclipse code. Therefore this is a blocker we hit as soon as we imported the code into 4.2. And these are actions contributed thru some custom extension points created by us in some other plugin. 

Some people can contribute actions to my View thru our custom extension point. Will def evaluate the use of ui.menus and contribute to the View ID in its Contribution URI. 

But interested to know the solution to this problem also